# How to read a character input in a bootloader? (nasm)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I want my code to read a character input, and then store it in ax.

What I tried in function 'readInput':

```
mov ah,0h   ;get character from keyboard
int 16h     ;and store it in AL
mov ah,0eh  ;Display a character in AL
int 10h     ;aka, echo it
mov ax, al
int 10h
```

I'm getting an error that it is an invalid combination of opcode and operands at line 'mov ax, al'

So I wanted to store al firstly in a variable. Now, usually when its not a bootloader in the .bss section I'd put num resb 1. But there isn't any sections in the bootloader..? Where would I declare this variable, if that is what I need to do to make this work?

I tried the following to do it with a variable:

```
mov ah, 0h
int 16h
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h
mov [num1], al
sub al, 48
int 0x10
mov ax, [num1]
int 0x10
```

where I declared 'num1 resb 1' in 'done' function at the end, which has ret as its first line. But I am seeing it print sort of endlessly when I do that.

Here is my code for a square of size user input, which is why i'm trying to use the ax register:

```
call readInput
outer_loop:
mov bx, ax
inner_loop:
    call dot
    dec bx
    cmp bx, 0
    jg inner_loop
call newline
dec ax
cmp ax, 0
jne outer_loop
call newline
```

Thanks for help.

@Jester

Taking into account what you said, I felt like al would already store the number I want so there is no need to try to put it in ax. However this solution also doesn't work:

```
call readInput  
outer_loop:
mov bx, ax
inner_loop:
    call dot
    dec bx
    cmp bx, 0
    jg inner_loop
call newline
dec ax
cmp ax, 0
jne outer_loop
call newline 

readInput:
mov ah, 0h
int 16h
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h
mov ah, 0
int 10h
```

Comment: If you are writing a bootloader you should already be familiar with basic architecture things, such as `ax` being 16 bit and `al` being 8 bit so you can't move between them. If you want to extend it, you can use `movsx`,`movzx` or simply zero `ah`. Also remember `al` is the low 8 bits of `ax`.

Comment: @Jester Could you maybe clarify the registers for me? As you can see, ax is what I am taking in for the size of my square. Usually this would be e.g. 'mov ax, 10'. Since I am storing the number that I want in AL, what exactly does this mean to me? If I for example put 5 in, how would u make a code that is equivalent to 'mov ax, 5' from that? Or more like, if the code is 'mov ax, 5' what would be in ah and al at that point?I am having difficulty understanding this... if al is the lower register and ah is higher, it seems me like after I read the input, al would store 5 and ah = 0. Why is it not

Comment: @Jester the case? When I tried that, I still had it print infinite dots.

Comment: You can do `movzx ax, al` or `mov ah, 0` or `xor ah, ah` to zero extend `al` into `ax`.

Comment: @Jester I tried it with mov ah, 0. I am now getting the dots decreasing by one every row, so its still not what I wanted. Could you have a look again please.

Comment: What do you think `dec ax` does? Of course you get one less if you decrement it.

Comment: @Jester I previously had a working code to output a 10x10 square in bootloader, just without user inputting the size of the square. This code already included dec ax, and it was to run through a total of 10 lines, decreasing each time it goes onto a new line, I believe. If I currently had 5 in ax like I did have 10 back then with 'mov ax, 10', it would behave the same..?

Comment: I also tried to replace 16h with 80h. Results still not what I expect... I am programming from linux command.

Comment: Can you just provide your entire bootloader and make this an [mcve]

Comment: to output a square, you have to output N times N dots, so you need source of N for every line, count-down counter for line (second N, reset at every line from the first), and count-down counter for rows (third N, decrementing every line). So you can allocate three spare registers for this, like for example `bp` having original N, `cx` counting per line (being initialized by value from `bp` on start of line), and `bx` counting lines (initialized by `bp` only once before outer loop). This is completely unrelated to bootloaders, it's programming basics, why bootloader?? Complicates things...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use different registers in the square loops and turn the keyboard input into integer.